# Why does Azo coupling of β-naphthol takes place at alpha position and not at gamma position

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I have searched for coupling reaction of $\beta$-naphthol with benzene diazonium salt at quite a few places. But everywhere the coupling has been shown at alpha position. Why doesn't it take place at gamma position to minimise steric hindrance.

Chemistry LibreTexts

[image]

Chemguide

[image]

My book

[image]

Comment: It is already addressed here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97067/mechanism-of-formation-of-2-naphthol-red-dye-aka-sudan-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coupling reaction of β-naphthol with benzene diazonium is an example of electrophilic aromatic substitution.

If the electrophile attacks at alpha position ,then two resonance structures 1 and 2 , with aromatic rings are possible.

[image] 
If the electrophile attacks at gamma position ,only one resonance structures 3 , with aromatic ring is possible and 4 is not aromatic.

[image]

Therefore attack at alpha position is the major product.

**References**:

https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2015/gc/c4gc02381a

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azo_coupling

[Mechanism of formation of 2-naphthol red dye (aka Sudan 1)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97067/mechanism-of-formation-of-2-naphthol-red-dye-aka-sudan-1)