Deciding the site of electrophilic aromatic substitution in a naphthalene derivative in the Griess test
The Griess test is used to detect the presence of nitrite ion in solution:



Why does the attack on the diazonium with N-(1-naphthyl)ethylenediamine (step 2) takes place from that position when the corresponding position on the adjacent ring seems to be richer due to less inductive effect while the resonance effect is tied?

Resonance effect isn't tied, adjacent ring is less activated, afaik.

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115172/why-does-azo-coupling-of-%ce%b2-naphthol-takes-place-at-alpha-position-and-not-at-gam

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138267/regioselectivity-in-coupling-reactions-of-%ce%b1-naphthol
