# Electrophilic aromatic substitution of napthalene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

It is known that the $\alpha$-position (or 1-position) for napthalene is the preferable position for substitution to occur at. However, I am getting two different explanations as to why this is the case, one of which I am not able to make sense of.

The first explanation which I have come across and which is also the one I am able to make sense of is given by Hepworth, Waring and Waring (2002). They explain it by using the concept of Clar's rule. With an attack at the $\alpha$-position, there would be two resonance structures in the intermediate with preservation of the aromatic sextet. With an attack at the $\beta$-position, there would only be one resonance structure in the intermediate with preservation of the aromatic sextet. As such, the $\alpha$ attack would be more preferable since the resultant intermediate would be more stable.

The second explanation which I have come across just today comes from Carey and Sundberg (2007). An image of the section of the text discussing the issue is shown below.

[image]

I am not able to understand why they have mentioned that the intermediate resulting from $\beta$ attack is not under allylic stabilisation because it seems to me that it is under such stabilisation, after drawing out the resonance structures. I would like to clarify if this explanation is accurate.

**References**

Carey, F. A., & Sundberg, R. J. (2007). Advanced Organic Chemistry Part A. Structure and Mechanisms (5th ed.). Springer.

Hepworth, J. D., Waring, D. R., & Waring, M. J. (2002). Aromatic Chemistry. United Kingdom: The Royal Society of Chemistry.

Comment: Related: [Thermodynamic vs Kinetic Sulphonation of Naphthalene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/thermodynamic-vs-kinetic-sulphonation-of-naphthalene)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, both descriptions are identical. However, they use different phrasings.

What Carey and Sundberg mean when they say *no allylic stabilisation* is essentially that the cation itself is not in an allylic position; that there is no *single* (non-phenylic) double bond in α-position. To reach the allylic double bond in the β-attack case, you would need to resonate across at least part of the phenyl ring (meaning you’re already making use of benzylic stabilisation) while in the case of α-attack you have access to allylic resonance without interrupting the phenyl resonance.

Comment: Your answer has really cleared things up for me. So there is no allylic stabilisation from a non-phenylic double bond in the case of the intermediate resulting from beta attack. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation is a hybrid of the two: the more stable intermediate resonance form has allylic stabilization *and* preserves the Clar sextet. You can only draw resonance forms with one or the other in the beta substitution intermediate.