# Solvent Effects in Friedel–Crafts Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

While reading about the factors affecting the product of Friedel–Crafts acylation with acetyl chloride, I came across a reaction involving napthalene in two different solvents: in nitrobenzene substitution took place at the beta position; in carbon disulphide substitution took place at the alpha position.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Alpha substitution gives the kinetic product while beta substitution gives the thermodynamic product. But exactly how the choice of solvent influences the pathway of substitution is quite interesting...

Comment: It should be related to shapes and effective volumes of the substrates and the solvents. Though I am aware that this is not a in deep explanation.

Comment: @Alchimista could you please elaborate. I'm just a beginner in organic so a thorough explanation of the concepts would be really beneficial for me

Comment: See [this earlier answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/thermodynamic-vs-kinetic-sulphonation-of-naphthalene/31712#31712) and keep in mind that running the reaction in refluxing nitrobenzene (b.p. 210.9° C) will pump a lot more energy into the reaction than when the reaction is run in refluxing carbon disulphide (b.p. 46.3° C).

Comment: Now there is an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Friedel-Crafts-acylation reactions, two types of Friedel-Crafts-acylation mechanisms, namely an ion pair mechanism and a dipolar ion mechanism, have been proposed (Ref.1).  Normal acylations are presumed to proceed via the ion Pair mechanism, which seems to be more important in sterically hindered reactions:

[image: F-C Acylation Mechanism]

The product complexes with aluminum chloride at the end. This complex liberates the final product after addition of water in the final step as shown in following diagram:

[image: Friedel-Crafts acetylation of naphthalene]

The Friedel-Crafts acetylation of naphthalene has been extensively reported and frequently studied as of today (Ref.1). Basically, two isomeric ketones, 1-acetylnaphthalene and 2-acetylnaphthalene, can be prepared by the reaction of unsubstituted naphthalene with acetyl chloride and aluminum chloride. A variety of solvents have been used for this acylation, and the solvent effect on naphthalene acylation has been studied intensively (Ref.1). The product ratio of 1-acetylnaphthalene to 2-acetylnaphthalene is found to be solvent-dependent. For example, when the reaction was performed in non-polar solvents such as $\ce{CH2Cl2}$, $\ce{CH2ClCH2Cl}$, $\ce{CHCl3}$, or $\ce{CS2}$, the 1-acetylnaphthalene formation is preferred and when reaction is done in polar solvents such as nitrobenzene or $\ce{CH3NO2}$, the reaction has proceeded to give 2-acetylnaphthalene,  exclusively. This phenomenon has been explained considering reversibility of the reaction:

> The aluminum chloride-acylaromatic complex is insoluble in non-polar solvents carbon disulfide, but very soluble in polar solvent such as nitrobenzene. The 1-acetylnaphthalene-$\ce{AlCl3}$ complex can form rapidly (kinetic product) and it would precipitate from the solution, preventing further reaction. On the other hand, the 1-acetylnaphthalene-$\ce{AlCl3}$ is soluble in the polar solvents such as nitrobenzene. Thus, the reaction proceeds further and 1-acetylnaphthalene would deacetylate, and the slower 2-acylation reaction may occur to give more stable thermodynamic product (Ref.2).

**REFERENCES:**

1. P. H. Gore, “The Friedel-Crafts Acylation Reaction and its Application to Polycyclic Aromatic Hydrocarbons,” *Chem. Rev.* **1955**, *55(2)*, 229-281 (https://doi.org/10.1021/cr50002a001).
2. Gary Warren Keen, "The acetylation of naphthalene and the formation of (chlorovinyl)naphthalenes therein," *The Ph.D. Dissertation*, Oklahoma State University, Stillwater, OK, 1976.
3. Wenpeng Li, Haibo Jin, Suohe Yang, Xiaoyan Guo, Guangxiang He, Rongyue Zhang, “An environmentally friendly acylation reaction of 2-methylnaphthalene in solvent-free condition in a micro-channel reactor,” *Green Processing and Synthesis* **2019**, *8*, 474–479 ( https://doi.org/10.1515/gps-2019-0015).